# Remove value arraylist java from input

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an array like this:

```
1101 "TV"
5531 "Baju Baru"
1425 "Mesin Cuci"
```

Then i want to remove "TV" from my Arraylist. So i must type "1101" then the value is remove. But if i'm wrong it show "code is invalid".

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBarang.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(listBarang.get(i));
}
System.out.println("Your code stuff: ");
int code = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
listBarang.remove(i);
```

Any answer?

Comment: I believe `1101 "TV"` is a String ? and you have an array of Strings?.

Comment: Yes 1101 "TV" is array of String

Comment: I think it is better for you when you use instead of the array a HashMap or an ArrayList with a Tuple.

Comment: Shouldnt `listBarang.remove(i);` be _inside_ the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Map to store your arrays and you can remove the TV element from the it. try this.

```
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1101,"TV");
    map.put(5531 ,"Baju Baru");
    map.put(1425 ,"Mesin Cuci");

    for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> hh : map.entrySet()) {
        if (hh.getKey() == 1101){
            map.remove(hh.getKey());
        }
    }

    System.out.println(map);
```

output without "TV"

```
{1425=Mesin Cuci, 5531=Baju Baru}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove(i) makes no sense outside of your loop. Move it inside and if the code equals the input remove(i).